# How do I install socialengine on localhost

Tags: installation, localhost, socialengine

Please I really need help in installing socialengine on localhost. I've tried but I've been getting 503's. Please any procedures, links to tutorials or videos would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do some research on google to find info. Show some effort to do this, ans I'm sure you will get somenthing, as many of us have learn much. Please read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask=)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I wouldn't have come here if I hadn't done my own home work. C'mon, no one who really wants to learn will ever ask for help if he/she hasn't tried every means possible. I came here because I had no where else to go to. I spent close to 4hrs googling and youtubing this topic. I chatted with the Socialengine team but they said they don't provide such support. I even tried some other sites like stackoverflow but got nothing. Maybe my mistake was how I stated my question. Thanks all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a good installation support tutorial from SocialEngine here - http://support.socialengine.com/php/customer/portal/articles/1667583-installing-socialengine

As boring as it is CHECK YOUR MINIMUM SERVER REQUIREMENTS here - http://support.socialengine.com/php/customer/portal/articles/1649350-socialengine-requirements?b_id=4311

You might also want to consider changing the error reporting level on your server. If you can find your php.ini config file you want to look for

```
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING

display_errors = On
```

See here about error reporting - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13402590/276220

By changing the error reporting level you should be able to see the line that's causing you the issue rather than just the 500 page.